# Can I use sample code from MSDN without Microsoft's permission?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, licensing

hi i am using the following code from msdn for internal use for my company:

```
using System;

public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

i wonder if this is illegal or i have to get any permission or license from Microsoft in order to use that. it is just a singleton pattern.the other one is page object pattern that is use for automation that i search online

Comment: This question is no longer fit for Stack Overflow as it is really asking a legal question, and as can be seen from the recently added answer, it's not clear cut. I will vote to protect it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use MSDN sample code without permission, as it's available under the [Microsoft Limited Public License](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc300389.aspx):

> This license governs use of code marked as “sample” or “example" available on this web site without a license agreement, as provided under the section above titled “NOTICE SPECIFIC TO SOFTWARE AVAILABLE ON THIS WEB SITE.” If you use such code (the “software”), you accept this license. If you do not accept the license, do not use the software.
>
> ...
>
> 2. Grant of Rights
>
> (A) Copyright Grant - Subject to the terms of this license, including
>   the license conditions and limitations in section 3, each contributor
>   grants you a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free copyright license
>   to reproduce its contribution, prepare derivative works of its
>   contribution, and distribute its contribution or any derivative works
>   that you create.
>
> (B) Patent Grant - Subject to the terms of this license, including the
>   license conditions and limitations in section 3, each contributor
>   grants you a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license under its
>   licensed patents to make, have made, use, sell, offer for sale,
>   import, and/or otherwise dispose of its contribution in the software
>   or derivative works of the contribution in the software.

Answer (score 1):

STW's answer is probably out-of-date. As of today, the link provided now lands here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/mdsa?redirectedfrom=MSDN, Microsoft Developer Agreement. Part of which says,

> 2. Software and Microsoft Content
>
>    Using Microsoft Software and Microsoft Content outside the Service. Microsoft may provide you with Microsoft Software or
>    Microsoft Content through or as a part of the Services. Termination or
>    suspension of this Agreement or of your use or access to the Services
>    terminates your right to possess or use any such Microsoft Software or
>    Microsoft Content unless separately licensed to you. The suspension or
>    termination of a User Plan terminates that user’s right to possess or
>    use any such Microsoft Software or Microsoft Content associated with,
>    or contingent upon that User Plan. You must delete all copies of such
>    Microsoft Software or Microsoft Content licensed under this Agreement
>    and destroy any associated media upon the termination of the
>    associated possession or usage rights. This subsection does not apply
>    to Microsoft Software addressed in subsection (b) below.
>
>    Software and Content on Documentation Portals. Third-party software and Content accessible on the Documentation Portals is made
>    available by the designated publisher under the associated license
>    terms.
>
>    Scope of rights. All Microsoft Software and Microsoft Content are the copyrighted works of Microsoft or its suppliers are licensed not
>    sold and may not be transferred unless specified otherwise.

So, it's not as clear cut as STW claims. Maybe the Microsoft Limited Public License still exists and still applies to code samples in Microsoft's documentation website, but it's not at that link.

Comment: And this is a golden example of why Stack Overflow doesn't consider questions about licensing as on-topic. The only way to get a working answer is to consult a lawyer. For instance, it may be that since the code was copied from the website when the previous license was in effect that the license still holds, it cannot be retroactively modified to make previous usages prohibited, but the only person who could really answer this kind of detailed question would be a lawyer, and not a developer.